# Changing string to int from a list of lists only for isdigit

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list called rawSafirlistoflists and I work with python 3, that is looking like this:

```
[['423523525', 'HOROS', 'WAFAD', ' 23523523523 - HOROD WAFAD', 'August', '2014', '540', '0', 'Ianuarie', '2015', '0', '0', 'RESTANTA_MANDAT', 'Mandat neachitat NAM', '', 'AJUTOR REFUGIATI', 'INCLUS_IN_PLATA', ''], ['5235232', 'STOICOVICIDF', 'PAULADD ANDREEAD', ' 52352352352 - STOICOVICIDE PAULF CRISTIAN', 'August', '2014', '42', '0', 'Februarie', '2015', '0', '0', 'RESTANTA_MANDAT', '', '', 'ALOCATIA DE STAT PENTRU COPII', 'INCLUS_IN_PLATA', '']]
```

There I want to iterate and transform only the numbers that are now string to int.
This is my code:

```
for level1 in rawSafirlistoflists:
for level2 in level1:
    if level2.isdigit():
        int(level2)
        print(level2)
print (rawSafirlistoflists)
```

When I print the level2 I see that the if had found the right string (the ones that are numbers) and converted them in int as I wanted, but it isn't saving the change. My problem at the end when I print my list rawSafirlistoflists the values are unchanged (all indexes remained strings), how can I push the modifications at the if statement so the values to remain as int?

Comment: Since indentation is **syntactically critical** in Python, and your code isn't properly indented, we can't tell what you mean. Please correct your code.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to basically understand how python works (`int(level2)` doesn't change `level2`, and I don't see how you could even come to the conclusion it does) , so I'm afraid this question is too broad. Find (another?) good python tutorial and start reading, would probably be my advice here.

Comment: That was actually my question, what I can do there in order to change that values in my original list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.isdigit` is the right approach, but `int(level2)` is doing nothing (useful). The call to `int` returns an integer value which you then discard, it does not mutate the string `level2`. (In fact, strings don't have any mutating methods on them.)

In order to fix your approach (after fixing indentation), create a new list to which you append the return values of the calls to `int` (or the original value, in case `str.isdigit` returns `False`).

This could also be done with a list comprehension as follows.

```
>>> mylist = ['123', 'not-an-int', '456']
>>> converted = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in mylist]
>>> converted
[123, 'not-an-int', 456]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `list comprehension`,

```
result = [int(j) if j.isdigit() else j for i in a for j in i]
```

Assumed `a` as your input.

**Execution:**

```
In [20]: result = [int(j) if j.isdigit() else j for i in a for j in i]

In [21]: print result
[423523525, 'HOROS', 'WAFAD', ' 23523523523 - HOROD WAFAD', 'August', 2014, 540, 0, 'Ianuarie', 2015, 0, 0, 'RESTANTA_MANDAT', 'Mandat neachitat NAM', '', 'AJUTOR REFUGIATI', 'INCLUS_IN_PLATA', '', 5235232, 'STOICOVICIDF', 'PAULADD ANDREEAD', ' 52352352352 - STOICOVICIDE PAULF CRISTIAN', 'August', 2014, 42, 0, 'Februarie', 2015, 0, 0, 'RESTANTA_MANDAT', '', '', 'ALOCATIA DE STAT PENTRU COPII', 'INCLUS_IN_PLATA', '']
```

Comment: That wont keep my original format of lists of list. I will get one single list.

Comment: @Rommel it's trivial to adjust your code accordingly. Answers are meant to be useful for other readers, too.

Comment: @timgeb, I agree with you. BTW Your answer is Nice one.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
for index in range(len(list)):
    for index2 in range(len(list[index])):
        if list[index][index2].isdigit():
             list[index][index2] = int (list[index][index2])
```

You wasn't saving the element back to the list

Comment: [That's not how you loop in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o) (to be precise, make use of the `enumerate` builtin)

Comment: Thanks for the advice